# x13_arima_analysis: neither x12a nor x13ab available for Windows binaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

Many of those who have used `x13_arima_analysis` will have seen something like this before now.

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
>>> results = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(list(range(23)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py", line 408, in x13_arima_analysis
    x12path = _check_x12(x12path)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py", line 84, in _check_x12
    raise X13NotFoundError("x12a and x13as not found on path. Give the "
statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions.X13NotFoundError: x12a and x13as not found on path. Give the path, put them on PATH, or set the X12PATH or X13PATH environmental variable.
```

One of the first things that `x13_arima_analysis` does is to check for the availability of either `x12a` or `x13as`. The error diagnostic offers obvious remedies.

However, the installation file `statsmodels-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl` that I used to get `statsmodels` does not seem to provide files with either of these names. (I've searched the entire drive where I installed the product for them.)

Would anyone happen to know where Windows 64-bit binaries might be available?

Comment: x13 needs to be separately installed, independently of statsmodels. https://www.census.gov/srd/www/winx13/winx13_down.html . statsmodels does not bundle third-party products or packages.

Comment: I ran into this issue a while back. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945324/python-statsmodels-x13-arima-analysis-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-att

Comment: @user333700: That did it, as you would know. Many thanks.

Comment: @Jarad: Thanks for the suggestion. Regret I couldn't make it work. I actually have newest available Windows version.