# Which Seasonal Adjustment Program should I use with Statsmodels X-13-ARIMA

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I have downloaded Win X-13 [from Census](https://www.census.gov/data/software/x13as.Win_X-13.html#list-tab-635278563), and unpacked it on my drive.

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import os
import statsmodels.api as sm

s = pd.Series(
    {Timestamp('2013-03-01 00:00:00'): 838.2,
     Timestamp('2013-04-01 00:00:00'): 865.17,
     Timestamp('2013-05-01 00:00:00'): 763.0,
     Timestamp('2013-06-01 00:00:00'): 802.99,
     Timestamp('2013-07-01 00:00:00'): 875.56,
     Timestamp('2013-08-01 00:00:00'): 754.4,
     Timestamp('2013-09-01 00:00:00'): 617.48,
     Timestamp('2013-10-01 00:00:00'): 994.75,
     Timestamp('2013-11-01 00:00:00'): 860.86,
     Timestamp('2013-12-01 00:00:00'): 786.66},
    name='Cost')

PATH = os.chdir(r'C:\WinX13\x13as')

result = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(s, x12path=PATH)
```

This return error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [10], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 PATH = os.chdir(r'C:\Users\usr\WinX13\x13as')
----> 3 result = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(s, x12path=PATH)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:207, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    205     else:
    206         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 207 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py:457, in x13_arima_analysis(endog, maxorder, maxdiff, diff, exog, log, outlier, trading, forecast_periods, retspec, speconly, start, freq, print_stdout, x12path, prefer_x13, tempdir)
    455     print(p.stdout.read())
    456 # check for errors
--> 457 errors = _open_and_read(ftempout.name + '.err')
    458 _check_errors(errors)
    460 # read in results

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py:206, in _open_and_read(fname)
    204 def _open_and_read(fname):
    205     # opens a file, reads it, and make sure it's closed
--> 206     with open(fname, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as fin:
    207         fout = fin.read()
    208     return fout

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\usr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp0d23o_q8.err'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I donwloading the wrong Seasonal Adjustment Program? Or using it wrong. I found little help online. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945324/python-statsmodels-x13-arima-analysis-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-att) solution from SO did not helt me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone have similar issues, I needed to download another [Seasonal Adjustment Program](https://www.census.gov/data/software/x13as.X-13ARIMA-SEATS.html#list-tab-635278563) to make this work. Scroll down to Previous Versions and download Version 1.1. Ascii-version works for me.